# Opening personal bank account in Marbella, as a non-EU resident

Tags: bank-account, non-resident, spain

I'm going to Marbella, Spain, soon. I would like to open an account in one of banks of that place during my times there. Could you suggest how hard is it to do for non-resident of the country? I'm from Russia, and I will be travelling on a Tourist Visa. If I can to open it - which documents will I need? Is a foreign passport enough for this or not? Also, maybe someone could advise a bank's name which is good, if it's possible to do.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about travel

Comment: Okay, how can I move it there? Or can administrators do this? Thanks.

Comment: @Evgeniy flag the question, choose *other* and then explain that you want your question to be migrated

Comment: @HaLaBi What? How is a question about traveling to a place (on a tourist visa, to boot) and doing something in that place not a travel question?

Comment: @Gilles How to open an account during travel is more of money question not a travel question. Not because you add (while travelling) then the question is on-topic. This is just my opinion :)

Comment: @Gilles normally tourist not able open bank account in other country. You should have a citizen / permanent resident ID to do this.

Comment: @Rudy No, not always. It depends a lot on the country (which makes this a relevant question to travel), but often all you need is an address in that country and a valid visa even if it's a short-term one. And sometimes not even that.

Comment: Yes, I've read that people go abroad and open bank accounts during travels. I found that Deutsche Bank has an office in Marbella. What do you think will they help with this question?

Answer (score 2):

You'll be asked for certification of non-residency ([certificado de no residencia](http://extranjeros.empleo.gob.es/es/InformacionInteres/InformacionProcedimientos/Ciudadanosnocomunitarios/hoja093/)), which can be obtained either from Spanish consulate in your country or from Dirección General de la Policía in Spain. Some banks can actually manage that for you for a small fee. Besides that you'll of course need your passport. Some banks might require for you to put some initial money on the account (at most few hundred euros), but YMMV.

Comment: Yes, money for the account are not a problem. Okay, thanks, I think I just go and ask. My anxieties are that large banks could have a more aspirations for an account opening.

Comment: @Evgeniy: not really, it's more if you want their services for free, then they usually require to be set as the bank where your salary is transferred too. But if you willing to pay for upkeeping the account and don't need credit card from that bank, not much is required.